# How to trace fail scenario in cucumber for test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara, gherkin

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec cucumber features/bodybuilder/notworking.feature --backtrace
```

I have used the above command with different parameter but no success for me 
1. --backtrace
2. --format (OptionParser::MissingArgument) <== it gives me this 
3. --verbose --backtrace  <== this does not show correct way of output
4. --trace (OptionParser::InvalidOption) <== it gives me this

It does not give me where Scenario fails exactly

o/p: for backtrace

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories):
>   .git
>  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent
>   directories): .git
>  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the
>   parent directories): .git
>  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of
>   the parent directories): .git
>  re-use db:
>   dxbi_2f921362a97c1_725257_test
>  Using the default profile...
>   .........F
>
> Failing Scenarios:
>  cucumber
>   features/bodybuilder/notworking.feature:19 # Scenario: Create new
>   bodybuilder
>
> 1 scenario (1 failed)
>  6 steps (6 passed)
>  0m11.148s

The Scenario using:

> @javascript
>   Scenario: Create new bodybuilder
>       When I click on Create New bodybuilder button
>       Then I check the checkbox "MobileClick" from bodybuilder gym
>       And  I fill in "Name" with "bodybuilderTest"
>       And  I click on "Create bodybuilder" button
>       Then I should see "Successfully created bodybuilder 'bodybuilderTest'"

The step gives us problem is this:

> When(/^I check the checkbox "(.*?)" from bodybuilder gym$/) do |checkbox_select|
>      within('div#first_party_bodybilder_table') do
>        if find("span", :text => "#{checkbox_select}")
>           find('td.selectable input').click
>        end
>      end
>   end

Here after clicking it gives that ...F over there else Scenario runs smooth but we need that to check.

Comment: With cucumber 1.3.15 a failure in a step definition shows me the line number, and -b shows the entire backtrace. So: what version of cucumber? Is this a Javascript scenario? Is there something non-default about env.rb (or any other support file) or cucumber.yml?

Comment: cucumber version using: **gem 'cucumber-rails','~>1.4.0'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am running under the virtual machine and test environment need to use following command

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec cucumber -b -f pretty features/bodybuilder/notworking.feature
```

It give full trackback of error occurring.